# Can I ask questions base on Islam medical science

Tags: discussion

Those this site appreciate any question that is base on health in Islam

I want to know if this site is related to a new proposed site on Area 51 which is called Islam medical science

Comment: Please take some time and elaborate and explain (maybe by example) what you mean to say or intend to ask see [ask]. As is you leave us guessing what you exactly mean.